# How to check the URL of current git repository with TortoiseGit?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I am new to git and have currently switched from Bitbucket to Github, but have not yet deleted the Bitbucket repository. I have a folder in my computer, but am unsure whether that folder is from the github or the bitbucket repository. Is there a way I can check the URL of the repository with TortoiseGit, and if so how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Git is a decentralized version control system and, thus, can have multiple remote repositories for a working tree.

The configured ones can be seen in TortoiseGit settings -> Git -> Remotes (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-remote).

Comment: Remember to click at least one item in "Remote:" list. Normally, there is "origin" in the list.  Press "origin" then you can see URL in URL text box.

Answer (score 18):

Go to your project folder and open the `.git/config` file. There you can see the remote urls.

Comment: When you use windows than you have the git bash and vim ;) use that.

Comment: Actually any decent Windows text editor works (e.g. Notepad++)

Answer (score 4):

I think that in the 'fetch' dialog, there is a 'manage remotes' link.